When quantity is changed, total is showing as NaN
I'm currently working on a clothing website as a personal project only dealing with the frontend, trying to get out of tutorial hell. I am having an issue with increasing the quantity of an item. Everytime I try to increase or decrease the quantity of an item instead of the correct price showing in the cart I get an output of $NaN. I feel like it might be an issue with the updateCartTotal function but I can't seem to find the exact spot that is causing the error. I haven't gotten very far into the actual programming part of it but this is the code that I have so far. Any kind of suggestions would be helpful.


// Update the price of cart based on the Quantity of items
const quantityChanged = (event) => {
  const input = event.target;
  if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
    input.value = 1;
  }
  updateCartTotal();
}

const ready = () => {
  // For loop for removing item from cart
  const removeCartItemButton = document.getElementsByClassName('far fa-times-circle');

  for (i = 0; i < removeCartItemButton.length; i++) {
    let button = removeCartItemButton[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
      updateCartTotal();
    })
  }
  // Get the number of items that the product has in the cart
  const quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quan-input');
  for (let i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
    const input = quantityInputs[i];
    input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
  }
}

// Check if Dom is loaded so no errors appear
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
  ready();
}

// Function for updating the cart total
let updateCartTotal = () => {
  const cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
  const cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row');
  let total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    const cartRow = cartRows[i];
    const priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0];
    const quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quan-input')[0];
    const price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ""));
    const quantity = quantityElement.value;
    total = total + (price * quantity);
  }
  document.getElementById('total-price').innerText = '$' + total;
  document.getElementById('cart-subtotal').innerText = '$' + total;
}

const sendProduct = () => {

}
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2480d3976a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="pro-details">
  <table width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Remove</td>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Subtotal</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="cart-items">
      <tr class="cart-row">
        <td><a href="#"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
        <td><img class="table-img" src="img/north-face-puffer.png"></td>
        <td>South Face Puffer</td>
        <td class="cart-price">$90.00</td>
        <td class="cart-quan-input"><input type="number" value="1"></td>
        <td>$90.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>

<section class="cart-total">
  <h3>Cart Total</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Cart Subtotal</td>
      <td id="cart-subtotal">$95</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shipping</td>
      <td>Free</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td id="total-price">$95</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button type="submit">Checkout</button>
</section>




I made you a [mcve]

You should not use IIFE methods in modern JavaScript. It is outdated and barely readable. YOu have better methods nowadays such as Classes and modular JS.

You are dealing with HTML collection when using getElementsByClassName. Your quantityElement is  a td that contains your input so you need to get your input value as well ( I added console.log(quantityElement) FYI. In order to get the input value you need to select it again with let theQuantity = quantityElement.querySelector('input').value (I console.log it as well)


// Update the price of cart based on the Quantity of items
const quantityChanged = (event) => {
  const input = event.target;
  if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
    input.value = 1;
  }
  updateCartTotal();
}

const ready = () => {
  // For loop for removing item from cart
  const removeCartItemButton = document.getElementsByClassName('far fa-times-circle');

  for (i = 0; i < removeCartItemButton.length; i++) {
    let button = removeCartItemButton[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
      updateCartTotal();
    })
  }
  // Get the number of items that the product has in the cart
  const quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quan-input');
  for (let i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
    const input = quantityInputs[i];
    input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
  }
}

// Check if Dom is loaded so no errors appear
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
  ready();
}

// Function for updating the cart total
let updateCartTotal = () => {
  const cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
  const cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row');
  let total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    const cartRow = cartRows[i];
    const priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0];
    const quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quan-input')[0];
    console.log(quantityElement)
    let theQuantity = quantityElement.querySelector('input').value
    console.log(theQuantity)
    const price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ""));
  
  

    total = total + (price * theQuantity);
    console.log(total)
  }
  document.getElementById('total-price').innerText = '$' + total;
  document.getElementById('cart-subtotal').innerText = '$' + total;
}

const sendProduct = () => {

}
<section class="pro-details">
    <table width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Remove</td>
          <td>Image</td>
          <td>Product</td>
          <td>Price</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Subtotal</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="cart-items">
        <tr class="cart-row">
          <td><a href="#"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
          <td><img class="table-img" src="img/north-face-puffer.png"></td>
          <td>South Face Puffer</td>
          <td class="cart-price">$90.00</td>
          <td class="cart-quan-input"><input type="number" value="1"></td>
          <td>$90.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
  
  <section class="cart-total">
    <h3>Cart Total</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cart Subtotal</td>
        <td id="cart-subtotal">$95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shipping</td>
        <td>Free</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td id="total-price">$95</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  
    <button type="submit">Checkout</button>
  </section>




The subtotal on the right is not updated and the code is still very non-DRY. I highly recommend delegation as I show in my answer.

@mplungjan Your code is no doubt much cleaner. My first goal was to answer his question and show the reason why he is getting NaN in his code and how to solve it. As per the subtotal it is updating the one on the left side which is the one he is selecting and changing its innerHTML not the one on the right side ( we can indeed easily change its innerHTML easily as well by either adding same class or another id..).  I also totaly agree with you that it is better using querySelector and classes

You were not accessing the input field in the selector.
Please delegate and grab the values by navigating within one row
The getElementsByTagName or getElementsByClassName are very clumsy compared to the querySelector from the row.
Note I gave the remove link a class as well as the last cell in the row


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const cartItemContainer = document.querySelector('.cart-items'); // tbody
  cartItemContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('.remove');
    if (!tgt) return; // not the remove button
    tgt.closest('tr').remove(); // remove the row
    updateCartTotal();
  });
  const updateCartTotal = () => { // Function for updating the cart total
    const total = Array.from(cartItemContainer.querySelectorAll('tr'))
      .map(cartRow => {
        const priceElement = cartRow.querySelector('.cart-price');
        const quantityElement = cartRow.querySelector('.cart-quan-input input');
        const subTotalCell =  cartRow.querySelector('.subTotal');
        const price = parseFloat(priceElement.textContent.trim().slice(1));
        console.log(price)
        const quantity = +quantityElement.value; // not really necessary to cast since we multiply
        const subTotal = price * quantity;
        subTotalCell.textContent = '$' + subTotal;
        return subTotal; // for summing
      })
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b); // sum
     
    document.getElementById('cart-subtotal').textContent = '$' + total.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('total-price').textContent = '$' + total.toFixed(2); // plus shipping
  };

  cartItemContainer.addEventListener('change', updateCartTotal);

  updateCartTotal();

  const sendProduct = () => {
  }

})
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2480d3976a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="pro-details">
  <table width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Remove</td>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Subtotal</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="cart-items">
      <tr class="cart-row">
        <td><a href="#" class="remove"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
        <td><img class="table-img" src="img/south-face-puffer.png"></td>
        <td>South Face Puffer</td>
        <td class="cart-price">$90.00</td>
        <td class="cart-quan-input"><input type="number" value="1"></td>
        <td class="subTotal">$0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="cart-row">
        <td><a href="#" class="remove"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
        <td><img class="table-img" src="img/north-face-puffer.png"></td>
        <td>North Face Puffer</td>
        <td class="cart-price">$100.00</td>
        <td class="cart-quan-input"><input type="number" value="1"></td>
        <td class="subTotal">$0.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>

<section class="cart-total">
  <h3>Cart Total</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Cart Subtotal</td>
      <td id="cart-subtotal">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shipping</td>
      <td>Free</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td id="total-price">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button type="submit">Checkout</button>
</section>




How about to set a ID or Name to the '< input type="number" value="1" >' element directly, like 'cart-quantity' etc.., then you'd able to read or write the value by document.getElementById('cart-quantity').value

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
